# Replacing values in a data with conditions

Tags: r

I have data frame in which one factor is Soil.pH and I want to replace all values of this factor that are bigger than 3 with the value 999.

Using the code `df[Soil.pH>3]<-999`   I get an error of duplicate subscripts for columns.

I should probably use the replace function like `replace(df,Soil.pH>3,999)`. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have some syntax error. `df$Soil.pH <- replace(df$Soil.pH,df$Soil.pH>3,999)`

Comment: this should work `df$Soil.pH[df$Soil.pH>3]<-999`

Comment: The most explict IMO `df[df$Soil.pH > 3, "Soil.pH"] <- 999`

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. Try this:

```
df$Soil.pH[df$Soil.pH > 3] <- 999
```

This will replace values in the data-frame.